# Is there MySQL offsest for update?

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

I have a table without primary key or unique key.

I want to update some values in nth records which order by date.

there is no offset for mysql update limit( like limit 1,2), how can I do this?

Comment: You'll have to look at MySQL queries that use a variable to create a rank value that resets when the value changes to get functionality similar to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY value) AS rank` because MySQL doesn't support analytic functions

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name
...
WHERE ids in ( SELECT ids FROM table_name limit ....)
```

Comment: Hi spinning_palte, unlucky, in this table there is no any primary key or unique key.

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but...

Can you create a temporary table? I'd suggest creating a temp table using the sorted values of the date field, selecting with the LIMIT clause. You can then update the original table using the values in the temporary table.

It would be something like this:

```
create temporary table temp 
  select date_field from mytable order by date_field limit 4,2;

update mytable set another_field='FOUND' 
 where date_field in (select date_field from temp);
```